# trying to create a table without using tables

Tags: css, html

What I am trying to do is create a 2 column table with sponsors names.  I am using css external file but every time I think I got it something throws a monkey wrench. For instance IE9  my first sponsor name goes way off the mark.

```
<div id="Sponsors">
<dl>
       <dt>
          <dd>
             <sp>Seth Jackson-Edward Jones</sp>
          </dd>
       </dt>
     </dl>
</div>
```

Here is the css I have been using in an external css file

```
sp{
position: absolute;
top: 279px;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
color: #D91D1F;
width: 206px;
left: 338px;
}
```

I think I am doing this wrong.  I want to be able to add more as I go.

Comment: why didn't use table?

Comment: Why would the use of invalid/undefined markup like `<sp>` and invalidly nested `dt` and `dd` be better than using a decent `table`?

Comment: cause i was trying to stay away from tables, they seemed old fashion.  I may be wrong on that.

Comment: Old fashioned is using table for layout purposes - storing the page header in the first row, storing navigation menu in the first column etc. Modern best practices frown on this because the `<table>` does not actually represent a table. You're making the same mistake by avoiding table too far - your `<dl>` is actually a table. There are good use cases for destructuring a table using lists etc - if the data is actually a list but the table layout is merely how you want to display it then it is valid force a list to display like a table.

Comment: been a long time since i did html or even css

Answer (score 1):

use `style="display:table"` for main container div

and `style="display:table-cell"` for the rows cell .

ull be able to get a table like structure.

Comment: this looks promising, but everything is on the bottom of the page

Comment: did not get u . Please explain a bit more

Comment: if u want it to stick to the bottom one simple way divide ur page as such the footer is say always 80% from Top this wway u can get a constant div in the bottom of the page

Comment: i have a rectangler area that this list of sponsors goes on.  I was hoping to do it with out tables.  the starting postion for the first is at top:275px; and left:335px;  that is on my doc problem becomes the one sponsor i put for test tends to shift all over in different browsers.  this is the problem i am having.

Comment: the problem is because ur using pixels instead of percentage try calculating the percentage of the top and left . it will take the values after calculating to its parent containers. different browsers render differently so u may get divs shifting right or to the bottom .